# Filter "woocommerce_cart_contents_weight" not applied for shipping weight

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, shipping-method

I'm trying to take account of the package weight in the total weight of the cart so I can bill the right shipping cost.

I tried adding a filter on 'woocommerce_cart_contents_weight' like explained [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40546790/change-total-woocommerce-order-weight)

So I added the following code snippet

```
function add_package_weight_to_cart_contents_weight( $weight ) {        
    $weight = $weight * 1.3; // add 30%     
    return $weight;     
}

add_filter('woocommerce_cart_contents_weight', 'add_package_weight_to_cart_contents_weight');
```

I've also added a snippet to print cart weight on cart page, and I can see that the weight filter isn't applied : The total weight of the cart doesn't change wether the snippet is active or not.

I also tried putting exactly 900g articles in the cart so that, with the box weight, it goes over 1kg and change price, but the shipping price is still the one for under 1kg.

Any idea on why it isn't applied and how I could fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works and only affects [`WC_Cart` method `get_cart_contents_weight()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.6.0/includes/class-wc-cart.php#L659-L675) usage.

Now for shipping methods, as cart items can be divided into packages, the weight is calculated for each shipping package and doesn't use [`WC_Cart` method `get_cart_contents_weight()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.6.0/includes/class-wc-cart.php#L659-L675). Instead it will make a calculation on the cart items for each package.

A possible way should be to use the filter hook `woocommerce_package_rates` to alter cost based on the package weight calculation. But this is going to be much more complicated as it seems that you are using 3rd party plugins.

Comment: So I have to directly alter cost, or can I alter weight using woocommerce_package_rates hook ? It would be great to only alter weight as cost is computed by the shipping method API.

Comment: @Raphael Understand that shipping weigh cost calculation doesn't use `get_cart_contents_weight()`. I suppose that you are using a plugin fro shipping cost based on weight… You will need to use some available hooks in this plugin if there is any or to make yourself the functionality that you are expecting instead of using the plugin.

Comment: The fact is I'm actually using several plugins from several shipping services, so that is why I wanted to modify the general weight, before the plugins gets to it.

I mean, the plugins have to get the weight from somewhere. So does woocomerce standard shipping cost system.
I do understand that it is not ```get_cart_contents_weight()``` that is used, but something has to be used, right ? The cart weight doesn't sudenly become a package rate.

I'll dig into the plugins to see how they get to the weight.