# Add an extra cost based on cart items weight to Woocommerce shipping rates

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, shipping-method

I have the code following placed in functions.php

```
function shipping_weight_fee( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;
    
    $extraFee  = 0;
    $total_weight = 0;

    // Loop though each cart item
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // Get product id
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

        // Get weight
        $product_weight = $cart_item['data']->get_weight();

        // NOT empty 
        if ( ! empty( $product_weight )  ) {
            // Quantity
            $product_quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];

            // Add to total
            $total_weight += $product_weight * $product_quantity;
        }
    }

    if ( $total_weight > 10 ) {          
        $extraFee = 20;
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'shipping_weight_fee', 10, 1 );
```

How can I get **$extraFee** from first code snippet to work in following code:
I tried with global but it does not work. I believe the second code runs first but I am not sure.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_shipping_costs', 20, 2 );
function custom_shipping_costs( $rates, $package ) {
    
    foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
        // Excluding free shipping methods
        if( $rate->method_id != 'free_shipping'){

            // Set rate cost
            $rates[$rate_key]->cost +=  $extraFee + 3;

        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Please help, thank You!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `WC_Cart` method `get_cart_contents_weight()` to get the cart total weight instead simplifying the code.

This will work if cart is not split in multiple shipping packages (see the other code below).

The following code **handle also the shipping taxes calculations**:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'additional_shipping_weight_costs', 10, 2 );
function additional_shipping_weight_costs( $rates, $package ) {
    $extra_cost   = (20 + 3); // Here define your extra shipping fee
    $total_weight = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_weight(); // Get total weight

    if ( $total_weight > 10 ) {
        // Loop through available shipping rates
        foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
            // Excluding free shipping methods
            if( 'free_shipping' !== $rate->method_id ){
                $has_taxes    = false; // Initializing
                $taxes        = array(); // Initializing

                $initial_cost = $rate->cost;
                $new_cost     = $rate->cost + $extra_cost;
            
                $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $new_cost;

                // Loop through taxes array (change taxes rate cost if enabled)
                foreach ($rates[$rate_key]->taxes as $key => $tax){
                    if( $tax > 0 ){
                        // Get the tax rate conversion
                        $tax_rate    = $tax / $initial_cost;

                        // Set the new tax cost in the array
                        $taxes[$key] = $new_cost * $tax_rate;
                        $has_taxes   = true; // Enabling tax changes
                    }
                }
                // set array of shipping tax cost
                if( $has_taxes ) {
                    $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Don't forget to empty your cart to refresh shipping rates caches.

---

#### Handling multiple shipping packages

As cart items can be split into multiple shipping packages by some plugins or custom code, in that case, you will use the following code that **handle also shipping taxes calculations**:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'additional_shipping_weight_costs', 10, 2 );
function additional_shipping_weight_costs( $rates, $package ) {
    $extra_cost   = (20 + 3); // Here define your extra shipping fee
    $total_weight = 0; // Initializing

    // Get cart items for the current shipping package (to calculate package weight)
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $item ) {
        $total_weight += floatval( $item['data']->get_weight() ) * $item['quantity'];
    }

    if ( $total_weight > 10 ) {
        // Loop through available shipping rates
        foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
            // Excluding free shipping methods
            if( 'free_shipping' !== $rate->method_id ){
                $has_taxes = false; // Initializing
                $taxes     = array(); // Initializing

                $initial_cost = $rate->cost;
                $new_cost     = $initial_cost + $extra_cost;

                $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $new_cost; // Set new rate cost

                // Loop through taxes array (change taxes rate cost if enabled)
                foreach ($rates[$rate_key]->taxes as $key => $tax){
                    if( $tax > 0 ){
                        // Get the tax rate conversion
                        $tax_rate    = $tax / $initial_cost;

                        // Set the new tax cost in the array
                        $taxes[$key] = $new_cost * $tax_rate;
                        $has_taxes   = true; // Enabling tax changes
                    }
                }
                // set array of shipping tax cost
                if( $has_taxes ) {
                    $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Don't forget to empty your cart to refresh shipping rates caches.

Related: [Filter "woocommerce_cart_contents_weight" not applied for shipping weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64416812/filter-woocommerce-cart-contents-weight-not-applied-for-shipping-weight/64417168#64417168)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add a fee to the cart you can avoid using the `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` hook and create a single function with the `woocommerce_package_rates` hook *(combining the two functions)*:

```
// set custom shipping cost by weight
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_shipping_costs', 20, 2 );
function custom_shipping_costs( $rates, $package ) {

    $extraFee  = 0;
    $total_weight = 0;

    // Loop though each cart item
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // Get weight
        $product_weight = $cart_item['data']->get_weight();
        // NOT empty 
        if ( ! empty( $product_weight )  ) {
            // Quantity
            $product_quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];
            // Add to total
            $total_weight += $product_weight * $product_quantity;
        }
    }

    if ( $total_weight > 10 ) {          
        $extraFee = 20;
    }
    
    foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
        // Excluding free shipping methods
        if( $rate->method_id != 'free_shipping'){
            // Set rate cost
            $rates[$rate_key]->cost += $extraFee + 3;
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*